# Описания действий при проверке запоздалых ответов

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Надо бы определиться что должно быть в конце предложений описания возможных действий при проверке запоздалых ответов:

[image: действия]

Во втором предложении есть точка в конце. В других её нет.

Возможно данную тему имеет смысл распространить и на другие случаи списочного перечисления.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В конце каждого предложения ставить точку.

Comment: Предложение каждого последующего пункта начинается с большой буквы. Значит ему (по правилам русского языка) должна предшествовать точка.

Comment: @Arhad, а ещё и в конце предложения тоже нужна точка: http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827463.html

Answer (score 0):

Не использовать знаки препинания в конце таких предложений.

Answer (score 0):

Во всех предложениях кроме последнего ставить точку с запятой `;`. В последнем предложении ставить точку.